# Internet connection being lost after about 10 seconds

Tags: networking, opensuse, startup

Okay so I have looked at this post [Network connection drops after a few seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/network-connection-drops-after-a-few-seconds),
Which looks similar to the problem I am having but I have only just got Linux and can't work out what to do.

## Before I start.

I have Opensuse 13.1.
This is running on a virtual machine.
Setting on my VM for network is NAT.

## Problem

When I start up the VM I have access to the internet for about 10 seconds.
Running `ifconfig` shows

```
# ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:CA:F6:EC  
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feca:f6ec/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1668 (1.6 Kb)  TX bytes:11704 (11.4 Kb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1700 (1.6 Kb)  TX bytes:1700 (1.6 Kb)
```

After about 10 seconds it shows

```
# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1700 (1.6 Kb)  TX bytes:1700 (1.6 Kb)
```

So I checked in `/var/log/messages` and found it had been killed.
Here is what I think is relevant in `/var/log/messages`:

```
2014-07-24T19:07:32.911997+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[4043]: Found user 'avahi-autoipd' (UID 499) and group 'avahi-autoipd' (GID 498).
2014-07-24T19:07:32.917851+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[4043]: Successfully called chroot().
2014-07-24T19:07:32.919814+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[4043]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
2014-07-24T19:07:32.921004+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[4043]: Starting with address 169.254.12.33
2014-07-24T19:07:32.925894+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[4043]: Routable address already assigned, sleeping.
2014-07-24T19:07:33.007838+01:00 linux-iqb5 network[3444]: Shutting down network interfaces:
2014-07-24T19:07:33.353730+01:00 linux-iqb5 systemd[1]: Stopping ifup managed network interface enp0s3...
2014-07-24T19:07:33.691423+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifdown[4098]: enp0s3    device: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
2014-07-24T19:07:33.703182+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifdown[4098]:     enp0s3    device: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
2014-07-24T19:07:33.778217+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[4043]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
2014-07-24T19:07:34.044757+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[4175]: enp0s3: sending signal 15 to pid 1418
2014-07-24T19:07:34.046056+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[4175]: enp0s3: exiting
2014-07-24T19:07:35.533803+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[1418]: enp0s3: exiting
2014-07-24T19:07:35.536473+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[4219]: enp0s3: received SIGTERM, stopping
2014-07-24T19:07:35.538001+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[4219]: enp0s3: removing default route via 10.0.2.2 metric 0
2014-07-24T19:07:35.540269+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[4219]: enp0s3: removing IP address 10.0.2.15/24
2014-07-24T19:07:35.542169+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.2.15 on enp0s3.
2014-07-24T19:07:35.543660+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv4 with address 10.0.2.15.
2014-07-24T19:07:35.545181+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Interface enp0s3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
2014-07-24T19:07:36.399152+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[4219]: enp0s3: exiting
2014-07-24T19:07:36.974262+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Interface enp0s3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
2014-07-24T19:07:36.975258+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv6 with address fe80::a00:27ff:feca:f6ec.
2014-07-24T19:07:36.976375+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a00:27ff:feca:f6ec on enp0s3.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Or better yet have a solution for this ?
Also if you you need any more information just let me know what you need and I'll try and find it.

This is what i get in `/var/log/messages`  when i try to restart the network service.
Hope this provides some useful information.
Restarted using `/etc/init.d/network start`
Ouputs only `redirecting to "systemctl  start network.service"` to command line

```
2014-07-24T20:36:46.875361+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup[5635]: Starting DHCP4+DHCP6 client on enp0s3. . . . . . . .
2014-07-24T20:36:46.912559+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup-dhcp[5722]: 
2014-07-24T20:36:46.928787+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup[5635]: enp0s3    IP address: 10.0.2.15/24
2014-07-24T20:36:46.938725+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup-dhcp[5722]:     enp0s3    IP address: 10.0.2.15/24
2014-07-24T20:36:46.946793+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup[5635]: enp0s3    DHCP6 continues in background
2014-07-24T20:36:46.956573+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup-dhcp[5722]:     enp0s3    DHCP6 continues in background
2014-07-24T20:36:47.180511+01:00 linux-iqb5 systemd[1]: Started ifup managed network interface enp0s3.
2014-07-24T20:36:47.287777+01:00 linux-iqb5 network[5216]: ..done..done    enp0s8        Startmode is 'manual' -> skipping
2014-07-24T20:36:47.297576+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifup[7472]:     enp0s8    Startmode is 'manual' -> skipping
2014-07-24T20:36:47.369663+01:00 linux-iqb5 network[5216]: ..skippedSetting up service network  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ...done
2014-07-24T20:36:49.221664+01:00 linux-iqb5 network[7499]: Shutting down network interfaces:
2014-07-24T20:36:49.385756+01:00 linux-iqb5 systemd[1]: Stopping ifup managed network interface enp0s3...
2014-07-24T20:36:49.688419+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifdown[7816]: enp0s3    device: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
2014-07-24T20:36:49.698333+01:00 linux-iqb5 ifdown[7816]:     enp0s3    device: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
2014-07-24T20:36:49.765709+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-autoipd(enp0s3)[6435]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
2014-07-24T20:36:49.987453+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[7892]: enp0s3: sending signal 15 to pid 6591
2014-07-24T20:36:49.991505+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[6591]: enp0s3: received SIGTERM, stopping
2014-07-24T20:36:49.992507+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[6591]: enp0s3: removing default route via 10.0.2.2 metric 0
2014-07-24T20:36:49.994813+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[6591]: enp0s3: removing IP address 10.0.2.15/24
2014-07-24T20:36:49.996912+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Withdrawing address record for 10.0.2.15 on enp0s3.
2014-07-24T20:36:50.002594+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv4 with address 10.0.2.15.
2014-07-24T20:36:50.006327+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Interface enp0s3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
2014-07-24T20:36:50.007898+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[7892]: enp0s3: exiting
2014-07-24T20:36:50.953700+01:00 linux-iqb5 dhcpcd[6591]: enp0s3: exiting
2014-07-24T20:36:52.299847+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Interface enp0s3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
2014-07-24T20:36:52.307888+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv6 with address fe80::a00:27ff:feca:f6ec.
2014-07-24T20:36:52.323000+01:00 linux-iqb5 avahi-daemon[509]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a00:27ff:feca:f6ec on enp0s3.
2014-07-24T20:36:52.531144+01:00 linux-iqb5 systemd[1]: Stopped ifup managed network interface enp0s3.
2014-07-24T20:36:52.676351+01:00 linux-iqb5 systemd[1]: Stopped ifup managed network interface enp0s8.
2014-07-24T20:36:54.450619+01:00 linux-iqb5 network[7499]: ..done..doneShutting down service network  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ...done
```

Contents of `ifcfg-enp0s3`

```
BOOTPROTO='dhcp'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR=''
MTU=''
NAME='82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller'
NETMASK=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'
```

Comment: It seems like your DHCP client has fallen (at least, when it comes to enp0s3). You should try restarting it, and see if it gives more information then. I'm not a SUSE user, but I believe something like `sudo /etc/rc.d/network start` should do the trick...

Comment: hi @JohnWHSmith i already tried that before posting the question, didn't know if it was relevant though. I have added the output to the question. Thanks.

Comment: What router are you using? What's the base OS? On the base OS, how much bandwidth do you have? (100, 1000 Mb?) Can you try running as "host" in Virtualbox?

Comment: Hi con7, `router -PCE-N15 PCI-E Adapter`, `OS- Windows 7`, Im not sure this is the bandwidth you're talking about but `bandwidth- 38Mbps` Also how would i run as host ?

Comment: @Jidder by bandwidth I mean the one you see when you go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` (write it in address bar) then select your network card, and click `status`. You will see "speed". Also, from what you wrote, PCE-N15 PCI-E Adapter, that's your wireless card, not your router. You are using wifi or cable? By "host" I mean the option in Virtualbox (http://i.stack.imgur.com/RaRwa.png)

Comment: Wifi but its on the same box as host which gets 38 Mbps.Do you mean on windows of linux for `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` ? Sorry i'm tired and misunderstood it, i have a `BT Homehub 4` router. Also i have tried the bridged connection with promiscuous mode as `allow all` but the same problem occured.

Comment: What happens if on the interface you change it from manual to auto?

Comment: @SailorCire Where do i change the interface ? Which interface do you mean ?

Comment: @Jidder you can do it in YaST or using your favorite editor you can change it in /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfh-enp0s3

Comment: @SailorCire Thanks for sticking with me on this, i have updated my answer to show what is inside the file. It looks like it is already set to auto ?

Comment: It does indeed. How about the output of `rcnetwork status` (OpenSuSE specific for people in the future)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms on a fresh install with opensuse 13.1 32bit on a virtual machine. For me, the solution was:

Edit /usr/lib/systemd/system/network.service and set `Type=oneshot` in the [Service] section instead of `Type=forking`, as proposed [here](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2013-11/msg02325.html)